# Can we use rvalue references for a parameter to be 'passed through'?

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

Is it possible to 'pass' a parameter through a function without copying?

Let's make up an example:

```
std::string check(std::string in, int &maxLen)
{
    maxLen = std::max(maxLen, in.length());
    return in;
}

//main:
    int maxCnt = 0;
    std::cout
        << check("test, ", maxCnt)
        << check("two tests, ", maxCnt)
        << check("three tests, ", maxCnt)
        << maxCnt;
// would output: "test, two tests, three tests, 13"
```

My c++ compiler foo isn't good enough to say if this may already be optimized away.

What would the signature of `check(...)` have to look like so that a temporary argument would **never** be copied?

My first guess was:

```
std::string && check(std::string &&in, int &maxLen)
```

If this is correct, what would the implementation look like?

Remarks:

- `std::string` is a placeholder, it should work with any complex type
- please hint me to any duplicate question

Comment: If you don't want to copy the object, pass a (`const`) reference...

Comment: @rubenvb So `std::string check(std::string const &in, int &maxlen)` would result in no copying regardless of the input being an lvalue or a temporary?

Comment: You'd need to return a (`const`) reference as well, otherwise the return value might need to be constructed.

Comment: @Martin You would copy it when you return the string. The signature would be `std::string const& check(std::string const&, int&)`

Comment: @Rerito I thought this would happen automatically through RVO?

Comment: @Martin You can't RVO something which has been passed in as a reference argument.

Comment: This question should rather be titled "Do we need to use rvalue references for a parameter to be 'passed through'?".

Comment: If this is a more general question I suggest you read about perfect forwarding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid any copy of the input string, you should write your function as:

```
std::string const& check(std::string const& input, int& maxLen) {
    maxLen = std::max(maxLen, input.size());
    return in;
}
```

The argument passed by `const` reference is pretty obvious. Why the return though? Because RVO cannot elide the copy here. RVO happens when you are building an object (an lvalue) in your function and return it (that includes lvalue arguments as well). The compiler elides the copy by automatically building the object where it is supposed to go. Here, if you return an lvalue (either `std::string const` or `std::string`), the compiler will see you want to store the return value somewhere and will have to perform a copy from your reference to that destination. By using a `std::string const&`, you will avoid that because the `operator <<` from `std::basic_ostream` handles const references as well.

To sum up, with the `check()` definition above:

```
int max(0);
std::string toto("Toto");
std::string lvalue = check(toto, max); // copy
std::string const& const_ref = check(toto, max); // no-copy
std::cout << check(toto, max) << std::endl; // no-copy
```

The overload resolution in the last call will chose:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
     operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
                const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
//              ^^^^^ const ref here for the string argument
```

Comment: You should add `std::string const& const_ref = check("Toto", max); // no-copy`, too, because that's the use case from the question

Comment: When you call `std::basic_ostream::operator<<`, the overload resolution will deduce [the right call](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)